# Change tests directory location in Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I want to use [VisualPHPUnit](https://github.com/VisualPHPUnit/VisualPHPUnit) for unit testing in Laravel. So I want my tests to be located in `VisualPHPUnit-master/tests` directory instead of the default `tests` directory.

I've already changed directory in `testsuite` element in `phpunit.xml`. Now when I write `phpunit` tests from the new directory are executed. But when I run `php artisan make:test TestyTest`, the test is written in the old `tests` directory.

How can I change the tests directory so that new tests are generated in another directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do it now. `tests` directory is hardcoded in the [`TestMakeCommand`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/TestMakeCommand.php#L50).

But you can easily create your own console command to achieve that.

Comment: Well I can edit the file you mentioned. It's not a config file but it's better than nothing. Thanks!

Comment: That can be a not a good idea. It can be overwritten when you upgrade Laravel. Instead, you can create a new command or even a command that extends `TestMakeCommand` and just overwrite the `getPath` method.